# General theory for 1st order matrix ODE "Z'(t) = A(t)Z(t)"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have an ODE of the form
$$Z'(t) = A(t)\cdot Z(t), \\ Z(0) = z_0,$$
where $A\in C([0;T];\mathbb R^{2\times 2})$ and $z_0 \in \mathbb R^2$ are given and solutions $Z\in C^1([0;T];\mathbb R^2)$ are being searched. Eventually, I want to be able to make statements of the form "if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are close to each other, then the corresponding solutions $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ must be close to each other". Is there any general theory about this form of ODEs and can you recommend good references? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existence and uniqueness of solutions follow almost trivially from Picard-Lindelöf for all linear ODE with continuous coefficients. This should be contained in any textbook on ODE.

---

You can use the Grönwall lemma on $d(t)=\|Z_1(t)-Z_2(t)\|$ where
$$
d'\le \|Z_1'-Z_2'\|\le \|A_1\|\,\|Z_1-Z_2\|+\|A_1-A_2\|\,\|Z_2\|= \|A_1\|\,d+\|A_1-A_2\|\,\|Z_2\|.
$$
so that with $a(t)=\int_0^t\|A_1(s)\|ds$
$$
d(t)\le e^{a(t)}d(0)+e^{a(t)}\int_0^t e^{-a(s)}\|A_1(s)-A_2(s)\|\,\|Z_2(s)\|\,ds.
$$

---

Let $\|A_k(t)\|\le L$. Then the Picard iterations $P_k$ have contraction constant $\frac12$ in the weighted supremum norm $\|Z\|=\sup_{t\in[0,T]}e^{-2Lt}\|Z(t)\|$. By the a-priori error estimate of the Banach fixed point theorem
$$
\|Z_2-Z_1\|\le 2\|P_1(Z_2)-Z_2\|=2\|P_1(Z_2)-P_2(Z_2)\|
$$
which again can be reduced to the difference $\|A_2-A_1\|$.

Comment: Another problem is that I actually cannot assume any uniform bounds on $A$. I was hoping to be able to bound the solution only in the $M_1$ topology.

Comment: You can always assume uniform bounds for continuous functions on compact sets.

Comment: I know, but in your approach, the bound of $Z_1 - Z_2$ depends not only on a bound of $A_1 - A_2$, but also on a bound of $A_1$, which is not what I am looking for. :( But probably, it has to be like this, when talking about norms $\Vert \cdot\Vert_\infty$. So, thank you for your help!